# Is filtering plus grouping in jquery Isotope possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's this website [big.dk](http://www.big.dk/#projects)  where I thought was using [Desandro's Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) but is actually an html5 canvas when I inspected it.

So what it does is it filters the items and also group it by year or by alphabetical order so that it lines up to its corresponding group vertically.

I have not seen any demos like this in the isotope documentations. Is this something possible in with the Isotope plugin or a totally different language?

Comment: I would like to know this too.